# Prove $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}\sin(i^2)$ diverges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I know $\int_0^{+\infty}\sin(x^2)\ \mathrm dx$ converges, but $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}\sin(i^2)$ diverges. How to prove it?

Comment: I would guess you mean $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sin(i^2)$.

Comment: Sorry.I mean $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}sin(i^2)$